# Laravel - gather data in array from 8 separate forms

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-7

I need to gather form data coming from 8 different forms. I would need all the forms to be subarrays and only have 1 array that holds all subarrays. The reason for that structure is that I will manipulate the content in different ways depending on sub-array.

Each form will have its own submit button, currently no need to submit all forms with one request.

Below is the code for 2 of the forms.

**Question:** If I fill in both forms, how come I do not see both [form_1] and [form_2] in print_r result at the last run of form?

A theory of how to solve it includes a constructor that would be responsible for merging all the sub-array forms data.

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [form_1] => Array
        (
            [user] => 123
        )

)
```

---

```
Array
(
    [form_2] => Array
        (
            [user] => 456
        )

)
```

**Wanted Result: (should be 8, only showing 2 for demo):**

```
Array
(
    [form_1] => Array
        (
            [user] => 123
        )
    [form_2] => Array
        (
            [user] => 456
        )

)
```

My code:

---

**[routes/web.php]:**

```
Route::get('/form-1', function () {
    return view('form_1');
});

Route::get('/form-2', function () {
    return view('form_2');
});

Route::post("/process_form_1", "FormHandler@result_1");
Route::post("/process_form_2", "FormHandler@result_2");
```

**[Form_1.blade.php]:**

## Form-1

```
<form action="/process_form_1" method="post">

  @csrf
  <label for="1">Name</label>
  <input id="1" type="text" name="user"><br>
  <button submit="button" name="button">Send</button>

</form>
```

**[Form_2.blade.php]:**

## Form-2

```
<form action="/process_form_2" method="post">

  @csrf
  <label for="1">Name</label>
  <input id="1" type="text" name="user"><br>
  <button submit="button" name="button">Send</button>

</form>
```

**[FormHandler.php]:**

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FormHandler extends Controller
{

```
function result_1(Request $request)
{

  $this->result['form_1'] = $request->input();

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($this->result);
  echo "</pre>";

// return (redirect('form-1'));

}

function result_2(Request $request)
{

  $this->result['form_2'] = $request->input();

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($this->result);
  echo "</pre>";

// return (redirect('form-2'));

}
```

}

Comment: So do you want all the forms to be submitted in one request?

Comment: @BenGooding No, each form will have a post button and should store content of one subarray, but since that subarray has a unique name it will not overwrite the data of the other 7 forms in the "master_array".

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do, when you make the request to the server it will make a new laravel instance to handle the request, and thus any objects (i.e. the controller object that you are trying to attach the request to) will be fresh, so new requests won't have access to $this->result, as it is a fresh instance of the controller. The only way to access it would be to store it in the database and then access to again, or send all the data from all the forms for each request. It's simply not possible (nor would you want it to be) to access data from a different request.

Comment: @BenGooding I see, it is possible though in plain PHP (outside Laravel). I will do a lot of processing where data is not needed to be stored in a db and can live in PHP arrays, until everything is done with processing then end-result can be stored in some kind of db. Seems a bit akward to store sub-parts of data in db and read out that subpart of data with need of gather them, and only then being able to use the data for processing.

Comment: You can look into using redis to cache data between requests which is probably the most common solution to this kind of problem

Comment: @BenGooding I give it a go with Redis. You can move over your comments to an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do, when you make the request to the server it will make a new Laravel instance to handle the request, and thus any objects (i.e. the controller object that you are trying to attach the request inputs to) will be fresh, so new requests won't have access to $this->result, as it is a fresh instance of the controller. The only way to access it would be to store it in the database and then access to again, or send all the data from all the forms for each request. It's simply not possible (nor would you want it to be) to access data from a different request.

You can look into using Redis to cache data in memory between requests which is probably the most common solution to this kind of problem.